How to Filter Device Visibility Based on User in ThingsBoard Dashboard?
I'm developing a ThingsBoard application where I need to control which devices are visible to which users on the dashboard. Specifically, I want to set it up so that different users can see different sets of devices; for example, user A should only be able to see device 1 and 2, while user B might have access to device 3 and 4.
Current Setup:
I have multiple devices connected to my ThingsBoard instance.
Each device has its own entry on the central dashboard.
Access levels are currently managed manually through user groups and permissions, but this setup isn't dynamic enough for my needs.
Goal:
Modify the dashboard dynamically based on the user logged in.
Implement a system where device visibility on the dashboard (like a filtered table) changes based on the user's permissions or assigned group.
Questions:
How can I configure ThingsBoard so that dashboard widgets dynamically adjust which devices are visible based on the logged-in user’s permissions?
What methods or features in ThingsBoard can be used to set up dynamic visibility rules for devices on a dashboard?
Are there any best practices or common approaches within ThingsBoard for managing user-specific content visibility?

You can make two customers and their respective groups and after that, you can assign the device with those groups and so those customers will see the devices as per your choice. So in these customers, you can assign the dashboards to that customer and can use the device visualizations. So both the customer will have their devices and dashboards. Thingsboard is not that dynamic that it can adjust directly to user login to the device's dashboard you will have to set up these things statically from your tenant profile for each customer and their respective dashboards.
